# New chat room, Old ID.

Tags: discussion, chat

[This](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8/ecmascript) chat room was recently created (well, the info page says Jan 10) but has assumed the very low room number of 8. How did this happen? Was the 'created' date reset? Did the room get recycled? Was there a former transcript that was purged?  It is my understanding room IDs are sequential based on creation order.

Comment: @Rob I have no issue, just curious. Never seen it done before.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Room 8 used to be "Tech startups & Companies" (https://web.archive.org/web/20150912100127/https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/8)

The transcript for that room has been moved to here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/28037069#28037069

Answer (score 26):

room owner here. No magic involved.

We asked a mod to reuse an old unused room ID so we can easily remember the link - the mod made sure the previous tenants were not interested in using the room and it was frozen for a while before that.